# Measurable multifunction

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}
\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose $ f (.,x, u) $ is Lebesgue
measurable for each $(x,u)$. Suppose also that $ f $ is continuous
at $ (x, u) $ for each fixed $t$.

Let $ g: [a, b] \rightarrow [a, b] $ be a Lebesgue measurable
function and $ U: [a, b] \rightrightarrows \mathbb {R}^{m} $ be a
Lebesgue measurable multifunction. Then the multifunction
$$
F(t,x) = f(g(t),x,U(t))
$$
é  $\mathcal{L}\times \mathcal{B}^{n}$-measurable
(Lebesgue-Borel)? Or should require continuity in $ t $ in the
function $ f $?

Note: Let $ T: \Omega \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ a space measurable. $T$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable if for each compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$,
$$
{x \in \Omega: T(x)\cap K \not= \emptyset}
$$
is a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable set.

Comment: This was crossposted from math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/395000/264. In the future, please wait some time before posting your question in multiple fora, and when you do, provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to see hear from you that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Comment: I asked this question in the math.stackexchange also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395000/measurability-of-multifunction